# App Store doesn't show Mountain Lion as installed

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

After downloading, and upgrading to OS X Mountain Lion, the Mac App Store shows a "download" link for it; it doesn't show "installed." Secondly, although I have downloaded it twice, it does not show between my applications.

Why does this happen?

Comment: This is completely normal. It looks for the ML installer (which is removed after installation to save space). Because its no longer on your system, the Mac App Store simply offers the option to re-download. There is nothing wrong.

Answer (score 5):

When you purchase Mountain Lion in the App Store, it will first download an application called `Install Mac OS X Mountain Lion.app` to your `/Applications` directory. When the download is finished you're automatically prompted with the following window:

[image]

After that Mountain Lion installs and reboots into your Mountain Lion install. The installer application will be automatically removed - because most users won't need it anymore.

If you open the App Store, you're offered you to **re-download** Mountain Lion (hence the button says "download"), which could be useful if you wanted to create an [install USB with the `.dmg` image](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/17/make-bootable-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-usb-install-drive/).

You can verify if you have installed Mountain Lion by going to the menubar and click: *Apple icon → About this Mac*. In case you have Mountain Lion installed, you'll see this:

[image]

Comment: Yes now I can be sure that it is really installed, thanks

Comment: @zeynep I'm glad to hear that! Please mark the answer as accepted so that other people will know this got solved. (little green icon under the arrows)